# How to display selected text, not selected value, of a dropdownlist in a displaytemplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I have this piece of code in my displaytemplate:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(blah => blah.InputtedData, ddv)
```

and I get an actual dropdownlist. I've tried this piece of code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(blah => blah.InputtedData, ddv)
```

And I get `1` (the number one), the selectedvalue. But I want to display `Yes`, the selectedtext. So how do I display the selectedtext in a dropdownlist in a displaytemplate and not the selectedvalue?

Per request:

```
namespace TESTMVC.ViewModels
{
    public class CtrlInputDataModel
    {
        public CtrlTypeModel RowCtrl { get; set; }
        public long InputtedDataID { get; set; }
        public string InputtedData { get; set; }
        public DateTime InputtedDate { get; set; }

        public CtrlInputDataModel()
        {

        }

        public CtrlInputDataModel (CtrlTypeModel newRowCtrl, long newInputtedDataID, string newInputtedData, DateTime newInputtedDate)
        {
            RowCtrl = newRowCtrl;
            InputtedDataID = newInputtedDataID;
            InputtedData = newInputtedData;
            InputtedDate = newInputtedDate;
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel that `ddv` is based on:

```
namespace TESTMVC.ViewModels
{
    public class DefaultValueModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public DefaultValueModel()
        {

        }

        public DefaultValueModel(string newLabel, string newValue)
        {
            Label = newLabel;
            Value = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think more information is needed here. Can you post the code for your model / controller

Comment: @EdCharbeneau: Info is provided.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: It is a long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it with the built in `Html.DisplayFor`.  However you can create a custom displaytemplate e.g. `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/DropdownListTest.cshtml` where you manually select the text from the dropdownlist values based on your property:

```
@model string
@((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddv"])
    .Where(s => Model == s.Value)
    .Select(s => s.Text).SingleOrDefault()
```

Then you can use it with the following (little bit complex) syntax:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(blah => blah.InputtedData, 
     "DropdownListTest", //template name
     new { ddv = ddv } // aditional view data: the property name needs to be ddv
})
```

But if don't plan to reuse this functionality just inline your the logic and use this instead of the `Html.DisplayFor`:

```
@ddv.Where(s => s.Value == Model.InputtedData)
    .Select(s => s.Text).SingleOrDefault()
```